# MySQL Query Syntax - works in phpMyAdmin but not on page

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my `users` table:

```
uid (main) | username  | password
    1      | Admin     | "(actual password removed)"
    2      | Dummy     | "(another password removed)"
```

My MySQL query is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = "Admin"
```

And my php code looks like this:

```
$con=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","database");
$sql='SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = "Admin"';
mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

If I run this code in phpMyAdmin, then it returns the first row successfully, however if I run it from my php page, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = "Admin") You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Admin"'
```

I don't get what is the difference...

Comment: Please post the PHP code

Comment: Where is your php code ?

Comment: what does var_dump($sql); contain ?

Comment: Why are you omitting the errors given by `mysqli_connect`? Can you post them up here. Your query might be failing if your connection has a problem.

Comment: @user1281385 string(50) "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = 'DJDavid98'"

Comment: @Swapnil Please don't edit the OP question to answer it!

Comment: that code works for me. are you SURE that your calling query ? as the error seems to suggest you are calling prepare ?

Comment: @budwiser What do you mean ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I misread your comment. Disregard ;)

Comment: @budwiser ok, no prob :)

Comment: @Koterpillar Those weren't actual passwords

Comment: @DJDavid98 are you using MysqliDb ?

Comment: @user1281385 I was missing the prepare line. Edited.

Comment: Re: passwords - better safe than sorry...

Comment: @DJDavid98: Just out of curiosity, how did you manage to get the `Fatal error: Problem preparing query` error? If you have pasted your code correctly here, the line with `mysqli->prepare($sql);` should cause a parse error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are supposed to use prepare on variables not the whole string. MySQL is escaping them to safer alternatives `&#39;`  which when viewed though a browser look like `'`.

Look up [MySQL Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and look in the examples section for how its supposed to be used

to make your code work, You could remove the prepare, or make the prepare apply to just the variable part (which in this case doesnt have a variable attached ?)

Comment: Glad its sorted. Not sure who downvoted ? What is the reason ?

Comment: I removed the prepare and it works, I don't see why it's incorrect.

Comment: The problem was caused by the preparing statement but not because what's described in this answer but rather because you don't use `mysqli_query` with prepared statements.

Comment: @budwiser How could I use it if it fails to prepare the query in the first place?

Comment: Its failed on preparing the statement with fatal. Hes not sending the query though mysql_query your correct - but what ive said happens and causes the error

Comment: @DJDavid98 when you prepare statements, you bind values and then call  execute() rather than query() i think is what hes getting at. Your code sample above wasnt reaching the query() line though because the fatal error was before it

Comment: @user1281385, that's right. This is the incorrect part in your answer: `you are supposed to use prepare on variables not the whole string`. Just not having any variables in the prepare statement doesn't make it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But Please try with **single quote**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = 'Admin'
```

Comment: Same problem with single quotes as well

Comment: If it didn't work with the backticks, MySQL's unlikely to be any happier without them

Answer (score -1):

Use single quote for the username string. Change this :-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = "Admin"";
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = 'Admin' ";
```